# setting a variable in an if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
if (x = (1+2) < 4)
```

Is the above snipped doable? Will it run as expected? I expect it to always set x to 3, and then run arguments if (3 < 4).

Comment: Try it and see!  I think you will find C++'s precedence rules surprising...

Comment: Best way to see if something works, is to test it yourself.

Comment: @JustinWood, In C++, I'm hesitant to say that's true. There are too many cases of something "working".

Comment: @chris something this simple can be tested in under a minute. If it were larger, I would agree.

Comment: @chris:  Fair point.  But, one should still try things (especially simple things like this), and if they get confused by the result, say "I expected X but I got Y.  Can you help me understand why?"

Comment: @JoeZ, I agree, I test things a lot, but you just have to be careful.

Comment: You should ask yourself if you really **want** to write such code. The mere fact that you got the operator precedence wrong proves that it isn't particularly good style. If you don't get it right, other people reading your code will not get your idea right either. Or they might, by accident. Code should express intent unambiguously.

Comment: @Damon is right, what do you think is better in that expression than say doing: `x = (1+2); if (x < 4) ...`? If you think there is a good reason to prefer the code in the question, speak up and let others help you understand that there is no advantage and there is one disadvantage: maintainability.

Answer (score 4):

[The rules of operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) make your condition equivalent to:

```
x = ((1 + 2) < 4)
```

So what this will really do is evaluate `(1 + 2) < 4` to get `true` and then assign it to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is achieved the following way

```
if ( ( x = 1 + 2 ) < 4 )
```